# How to make a Frame with Multiple Panels Like this

Tags: java, swing, layout, jframe, jpanel

I tried this Layout but Its shows only one panel.
I need leftpanel (Panel 1) a bit smaller than the second Panel.
It is currently showing the menu and Panel 1 in center.

I tried all of the every layout examples, but still could not get panel 2 to show.

I humbly await any advice that may help resolve my issue.

```
public PrintBillPanel() {
    GridLayout lay1 = new GridLayout(0, 2, 10, 5);
    mainPanel = new JPanel();
    mainPanel.setLayout(new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));
    printBill = new JPanel();
    showBill = new JPanel();
    printBill.setLayout(lay1);
    mainPanel.add(printBill);
    mainPanel.add(showBill);
    mainPanel.setVisible(false);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't set the sizes of either panel so they could be zero size. You also didn't do anything that would make the panels visually distinct. I am not sure why you are setting the mainPanel to be invisible. After setting the sizes and background so the panels could be distinguished the code worked.

```
java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(() ->  {
    JFrame frm = new JFrame();
    JPanel mainPanel = new JPanel();
    frm.add(mainPanel);
    BoxLayout layout = new BoxLayout(mainPanel, BoxLayout.X_AXIS);
    mainPanel.setLayout(layout);
    JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    panel1.setBackground(Color.red);
    panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(100, 300));
    mainPanel.add(panel1);
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();
    panel2.setBackground(Color.blue);
    panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(200, 300));
    mainPanel.add(panel2);
    frm.add(mainPanel);
    frm.pack();
    frm.setVisible(true);
});
```